# Are the two main characters in the movie inspired by any particular singer’s personal life or biographies?

Tags: character, a-star-is-born

In the movie *A Star is Born*, I couldn't help but notice the resemblance of Bradley Cooper's look to Chad Kroeger and Lady Gaga's look being very similar to Lana Del Rey. I couldn't also help but wonder if the movie had any inspirations from the personal lives of these two singers.

Comment: The movie is a remake of a remake of a film from1937 all of which deal with the same issues.

Comment: Yes Paulie_D the story does have a similar ring to it and thanks for the confirmation but I wanted to know about the characters too. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @Paulie_D .. I am asking about the characters reference to Chad Kroeger, Lana Del Rey. I have mentioned specific characters, kindly do not down vote my question..

Comment: @Shalini you might consider rewording your title slightly to emphasize that you are asking about the character inspiration and not the movie inspiration. The way it is worded sounds like you are asking about the inspiration for the movie which is probably why there is confusion and down-voting.

Comment: @Paulie_D it being remake didn't invalidate the question. And we can't be sure every user should know it beforehand

Comment: Basic research is expected and this would have solved part of the issues with the question. As the question has now been edited the issues have been resolved

Comment: I don't really see how the question has changed in that regard (or any regard really).

Comment: Thanks for the participation guys .. also if anyone needs any kind of change to my question one can always suggest changes .. that is if you think it improves the understanding of the question ..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So far I can NOT find a specific influence to Lana Del Rey or Chad Kroeger, but the following is what the film is inspired by...

The film is the fourth remake after the original [1937 film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Star_Is_Born_(2018_film)) of the same name. Others include 1954 musical, 1976 Rock Film, and 2013 Bollywood Film.

> **Background of the Original 1937 Film:**
>
> **Some film historians believe that the marriage of Barbara Stanwyck and
>   Frank Fay was the film's real-life inspiration. John Bowers has also
>   been identified as inspiration for the Norman Maine character and the
>   dramatic suicide-by-drowning scene near the end of the film (Bowers
>   drowned in November 1936)**. The film contains several inside jokes,
>   including Gaynor's brief imitations of Greta Garbo, Katharine Hepburn,
>   and Mae West; the "Crawford Smear", referring to Joan Crawford's
>   lipstick; and the revelation that the glamorous Norman Maine's real
>   last name is Hinkle. (Hinkle was the real last name of silent film
>   star Agnes Ayres, and not far removed from Fredric March's real last
>   name, Bickel.)
>
> **This film also has many similarities to the earlier film What Price
>   Hollywood? (1932), released by RKO Radio Pictures. The 1932 film's
>   original title was The Truth About Hollywood based on a story by Adela
>   Rogers St. Johns. St. Johns loosely based her plot on the experiences
>   of actress Colleen Moore and her husband, alcoholic producer John
>   McCormick (1893–1961), and the life and death of director Tom Forman,
>   who committed suicide following a nervous breakdown**.

However, there are NEW inspirations in the [2018 remake's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Star_Is_Born_(2018_film)) script, including Kurt Cobain:

> In January 2011, it was announced that Clint Eastwood was in talks to
>   direct Beyoncé in a third American remake of the 1937 film A Star Is
>   Born; however, the project was delayed due to Beyoncé's pregnancy.
>   **In April 2012, writer Will Fetters told Collider that the script was
>   inspired by Kurt Cobain**. Talks with Christian Bale, Leonardo
>   DiCaprio, Tom Cruise, Johnny Depp, and Will Smith to play the male
>   lead failed to come to fruition. On October 9, 2012, Beyoncé left the
>   project, and it was reported that Bradley Cooper was in talks to star.
>   Eastwood was interested in Esperanza Spalding to play the female
>   lead.

And there are several [Easter Eggs](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/10/a-star-is-born-original-lady-gaga-bradley-cooper-easter-eggs) pointing to other inspriations, including homage to Judy Garland 1954 film, **Lady Gaga's early career**, Lady Gaga's nose, Bradley Cooper's real life dog, **Cooper's character's back story inspired by Bruce Springsteen's autobiography**, **Bradley Cooper also shadowed Pearl Jam's front man Eddie Vedder**, and more!

Comment: Just to clarify the Q's title asks for ANY inspirations and the specific Q asks for two in particular, so I tried to answer both.